# Unable to change colour of ActionBar Title Text

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-components-android

I have this style:

```
<resources>

    <style name="ThemeTest.BaseTheme.Light" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeTest.Widget.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeTest.Widget.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Solid">

        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ThemeTest.Widget.ActionBar.Title</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeTest.Widget.ActionBar.Title" parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6">

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/clear_white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

It is supposed to show the actionbar title text (my app's name, by default) in clear white colour (#ffffff). But it does nothing. I can't make out any difference between the above style and this:

```
<resources>

    <style name="ThemeTest.BaseTheme.Light" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">

    </style>
</resources>
```

They look identical (the app name is in black).

I have tried several combinations of styles and widgets, but nothing seems to work.

The dependency is com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an **`ActionBar`** you can use:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.Actionbar</item>
</style>
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.Actionbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Surface" >
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: android:textColorPrimary seems to have worked (my theme inheritance hierarchy is different, but at the moment it is encouraging). I will do a few more tests and accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :** An easier alternative solution could be this :

```
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>ActionBarTitle </font>"));
```

**Solution 2 :** If you are using Toolbar in XML layout, try this :

> ```
> app:titleTextColor = "#FFFFFF"
> ```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite" />
```

Comment: Not sure how this helps. I need a Material Components solution (and a theme-inheritance solution). Does android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar even exist anymore?